# Запятая перед «и» в «не тот и не другой»

Tags: запятые

Мне кажется, запятая не нужна, но все же есть сомнения, поэтому спрашиваю.
Например в таком случае: «Это мог идти одноклассник, мог идти учитель. Или не тот и не другой, а кто-то вовсе неизвестный».

Answer (score 2):

***Это мог идти одноклассник, мог идти учитель. Или не тот и не другой, а кто-то вовсе неизвестный.***

Запятая здесь не нужна, так как местоимения соединяет **одиночный союз И**. Союз ИЛИ является присоединительным.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

Между однородными членами предложения, связанными одиночными соединительными союзами "и", "да" (в значении ‘и’), "да и", запятая не ставится:

**Примечание**

Запятая может ставиться при использовании повторяющегося союза И...И, но и в этом случае при тесном смысловом единстве запятая не ставится:

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом И, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство: *Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, **уходила и в ту и в другую сторону.***

Comment: Начал уже отвечать, обидно было стирать, когда увидел Ваш. ;)

Comment: Зачем же стирать. Хороший ответ у вас получился, короткий и ясный.

Comment: Спасибо, приятно! 

Answer (score 1):

Причин для запятой не вижу. При повторяющихся И в случае тесного смыслового единства (по Розенталю) запятую не ставят, но у вас даже нет повторений.